# cannot convert from threading task<bool> to bool gives error

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

public static class GetUsers
{
private const bool V = true;

```
    [FunctionName("GetUsers")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
    {

        string rv = "";
        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);


        // Required parameters come from the Request body
        string ClientID = data.Parameters[0].V.ToString();
        string TenantID = data.Parameters[1].V.ToString();
        string SecretID = data.Parameters[2].V.ToString();
        int PageSize = data.Parameters[3].V;
        //RequiredParameters to Select filter in a string array  default null
        string[] ReqPrm = data.Parameters[4];
        string FilterPrm = data.Parameters[5];
        UserCollectionResponse result = await graphclient(ClientID, TenantID, SecretID).Users.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
        {
            if (ReqPrm != null)
            {
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = ReqPrm;
            }

            requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = PageSize;

            if (FilterPrm != null)
            {
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = FilterPrm;
            }

        });
        

        var pageIterator = PageIterator<User, UserCollectionResponse>
          .CreatePageIterator(
              graphclient,
              result,
               // Callback executed for each item in
               // the collection
               (rsl) =>
               {

                   Console.WriteLine(rsl.Mail);
                   return true;
               },

              (req) =>
              {
                  //make new operations in subsequent requests

                  return req;
              });

        await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
        return new OkObjectResult(rv);
    }

   
    private class TokenProvider : IAccessTokenProvider
    {
        string CID = "";
        string TID = "";
        string SID = "";
        public TokenProvider(string CID, string TID, string SID)
        {
            this.CID = CID;
            this.TID = TID;
            this.SID = SID;

        }
        public Task<string> GetAuthorizationTokenAsync(Uri uri, Dictionary<string, object> additionalAuthenticationContext = default,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var token = adAccesToken(CID, TID, SID);
            // get the token and return it
            return Task.FromResult(token);
        }

        public AllowedHostsValidator AllowedHostsValidator { get; }
    }
    private static GraphServiceClient _graphclient = null;
    public static GraphServiceClient graphclient(string CID, string TID, string SID)
    {

        if (_graphclient == null)
        {
            var accessTokenProvider = new BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(new TokenProvider(CID, TID, SID));
            var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(accessTokenProvider);
            _graphclient = graphServiceClient;
        }
        return _graphclient;

    }

    private static string _adAccesToken = null;
    public static string adAccesToken(string CID, string TID, string SID)
    {

        if (_adAccesToken == null)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> V = new List<string>() { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            IConfidentialClientApplication
            App = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(CID)
                                    .WithClientSecret(SID)
                                    .WithTenantId(TID)
                                    .Build();
            _adAccesToken = App.AcquireTokenForClient(V).ExecuteAsync().Result.AccessToken;


        }
        return _adAccesToken;


    }
}
```

}

// the collection
(rsl) =>
{

```
                   Console.WriteLine(rsl.Mail);
                   return true;
               },
```

this part of the code true parameters gives thi error and ı cant solve it.I take the code from microsoft dcoumentations but ı cant work with it when ı tried it in console app it works but in Azure function it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `graphclient` is a method, so call it with all parameters

```
var pageIterator = PageIterator<User, UserCollectionResponse>
      .CreatePageIterator(
          graphclient(ClientID, TenantID, SecretID),
          result,
           // Callback executed for each item in
           // the collection
           (rsl) =>
           {

               Console.WriteLine(rsl.Mail);
               return true;
           },

          (req) =>
          {
              //make new operations in subsequent requests

              return req;
          });
```